# Can I create n identical entries in a list with LINQ?

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

I'd like to create a List with some number (n) of identical entries.

I could use a loop like so:

```
For i As Integer = 1 To n
    myList.Add(myEntry)
Next
```

Is there a shorter, LINQ-ier way?

Comment: Keep in mind, if myEntry is a reference type then with this code  you will get _n_ references to the same object in memory and not _n_ copies of the object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`Enumerable.Repeat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348899(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
myList.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat(myEntry, n))
```

Comment: Of course, if myEntry is a reference type then you will get _n_ references to the same object in memory and not _n_ copies.  (The same as the OP code)